# Python, append a class creation to a list a the same time

Tags: python, list, class, append

I want to create a list whilst a the same time create an object
The class object is the following

```
class Kanji:
    def __init__(self, kanji, trans, reading, words):
        self.kanji= kanji
        self.trans= trans
        self.reading= reading
        self.words = words
```

And I want to create the object whilst adding it to the list, like so:

```
lista.append(ひ = Kanji("火","fire",["ひ","び","ほ","か"],"Sample Text"))
```

But the following error pops up

```
TypeError: append() takes no keyword arguments
```

How could i do it?

Comment: When you write the code `lista.append(ひ = Kanji("火","fire",["ひ","び","ほ","か"],"Sample Text"))`, what exactly are you expecting the `ひ` to signify? In your own words, what is a list, and how does it work? If you had instead planned to make a list of integers, would you have written `lista.append(一=1)` and expected that to work and make sense? Why?

Comment: Do you want this `Kanji` object to be assigned to the list AND to a variable called `ひ`?

Comment: Your reply will make it easy to answer your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't assign to new variable

```
lista.append(Kanji("火","fire",["ひ","び","ほ","か"],"Sample Text"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanl you so much!

Comment: Accept if it is the answer

Comment: Excuse my delay